# .values() method on a datastructure in python

Tags: python, django

```
    _reg = {}
    def methodname(self, event, message):
        for s in self._reg.values():
             do whatever to s
 and not the following
 for s in self.reg 
           do whatever to s
```

I'm looking at this code and not sure why .values() has been called to the array? I would have thought this would have been fine

Is there an alternative to the values method ? I get it returns all the values.

Answer (score 1):

`_reg` is a dict, not an array.

Iterating over a dict gives you just the keys. `values()` gives you the values instead.